# Php regex reorder multiple line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, fread

```
[ITEM 1]  
defname itemname  
name just name  
id 953124  
value 52235  
color red  

[ITEM 2]  
value 522  
name hi  
id 5335  
color yellow  
defname thats 2
```

This is my `item.ini` file and there are a lot of items. As you see, the `ITEM` option orders are different from each other. I want to `fread` the file and `fwrite` it with the `ITEM` options in the order want (I already tried `ofc`). The order must be:

```
ID  
Color  
Defname  
Name  
Value
```

Comment: although this is a valid `ini`(?), but I think you are missing the `=` to determine `name` and `value` relationship, then you can use `parse_ini_file()` to parse the file

Comment: noo thats is not excatly .ini file. its just an example. so there are alot of types with out values under these values without =

Answer (score 0):

You can work this way:

```
// split whole file to get items in an array where each one looks like:
// 1]
// value...
// ...
$raw_items = explode('[ITEM ', file_get_contents('.../item.ini'));

foreach ($raw_items as $item) {
  // turn item lines into an array (see below about PHP_EOL)
  $raw_options = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($item));
  // get item #, which is always the 1st line, drop its ending "]"
  $item_no = substr(trim(array_shift($raw_options), 0, -1);

  foreach ($raw_options as &$option) {
    // turn option line into an array of words
    $option = explode(' ', trim($option));
    // get option name, which is always the 1st word
    $option_name = trim(array_shift($option);
    // populate clean items
    $items[$options[$option_name]] = implode(' ', $option);
  }
}
// then you can use $items[<item_no>][<option_name>]
```

Depending on your context, you may face issues about line-separators.
If so, get rid of that by replacing:

```
$raw_options = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($item));
```

by this:

```
str_replace(["\r\n", "\r"], "\n", $item);
$raw_options = explode("\n", trim($item));
```

Comment: i couldnt get it error here  
Notice: Undefined index: defname

Comment: @cafoob Did you test? Notably look at the resulting $items and see how it conforms (or not) to what is expected compared to input. Then if you don't understand where is the issue, post these informations.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a weird way to approach the problem, but we can solve it using regular expressions like your title reads.

If we had a string like this:

```
$string = '
[ITEM 1]  
defname itemname  
name just name  
id 953124  
value 52235  
color red  

[ITEM 2]  
value 522  
name hi  
id 5335  
color yellow  
defname thats 2  ';
```

We can use `preg_replace_callback`, which will extract each line of the string and send it off to a function of our choosing for processing.  Here, I say get me each part of `ITEM 1` as its own line and send it over to a function named `reorder_function`.

I have labeled each part above the expression so you can see where it's matching.  Then, I simply print out the new transformed string.

```
// MATCH THE PATTERNS, RUN THE MATCHES THROUGH THE 'reorder_function' FUNCTION AND SAVE THE RESULTS
//                                        1            2      3      4      5      6
$string = preg_replace_callback('~(\[ITEM \d+\]).*?\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)($|\n)~', 'reorder_function', $string);


// PRINT OUT THE RESULTS
print $string;
```

The `reorder_function` function looks kind of scary, but it's really not so bad.  Mostly I have a lot of comments taking up space.  It basically loops through an array containing the order you want each item in and while it's doing that, it checks each match to see if it matches "ID", "Color", etc.  When it finds a match, it writes that to a specific position within an array.  Once all of the positions have been filled out, the array gets turned into a string and `[ITEM 1]` gets its contents overwritten with the output from our function.  Then it moves on to `[ITEM 2]` and repeats the process.

```
// FUNCTION THAT WILL TAKE THE MATCHES AND ORDER THEM APPROPRIATELY
function reorder_function($m) {

    // SET THE DEFAULTS
    $order_array = array( 1 => 'ID', 2 => 'Color', 3 => 'Defname', 4 => 'Name', 5 => 'Value' );
    $final_output_array = array($m[1]); // DEFINE AN ARRAY AND SET THE [ITEM X] TO THE FIRST VALUE


    // LOOP THROUGH THE ORDER ARRAY
    foreach ($order_array AS $key => $val) {

        // LOOP THROUGH THE MATCHES THAT HAVE BEEN FOUND
        foreach ($m AS $match_key => $match_val) {

            // IF THE MATCH FINDS "ID", THEN IT WILL ASSIGN THE VALUE AT POSITION "1"
            // FOR EACH ONE, IT WILL ASSIGN THE VALUE UNTIL WE ARE OUT OF VALUES TO TEST
            if (preg_match('~^\s*'.$val.'\s~i', $match_val)) {
                $final_output_array[$key] = $match_val; 
            }   

        }

    }

    // TURN THE ARRAY INTO A STRING AND SEND IT BACK TO THE preg_replace_callback FUNCTION
    return implode("\n", $final_output_array)."\n";

}
```

When all is said and done, we get this:

```
[ITEM 1]
id 953124  
color red  
defname itemname  
name just name  
value 52235  

[ITEM 2]
id 5335  
color yellow  
defname thats 2  
name hi  
value 522
```

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/JtYZlx

Comment: Okey thanks a lot but (like always) i ve question for you. in my question string is just an example. There are some strings too under these values but wont order? is your code still work with them?

Comment: They should in that generally speaking, it's only going to match the parts in the `[ITEM X]` Newline, `Line 1`, Newline, `Line 2`, Newline, `Line 3` Newline, `Line 4`, Newline, `Line 5`, Newline (or end).  If there's other stuff in that file that doesn't match that format, it will leave it alone.

Comment: thanks again its working perfect, but how can i do with [ITEM a] i mean ITEM "string" its not working like that

Comment: ok i fix it like #(\[item (.*?)\]).*?\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)($|\n)#i that

Comment: Yes, that will work just fine.  The `\d+` inside the square braces means "at least one digit".  But if you are looking for something that is not a digit, you can do what you did `(.*?)` (although you don't need the parenthesis around it) or specify what it should be.  Like if it's letters you can use a character class like this instead `[A-Za-z]+`.  Or if it's letters and/or numbers, you can do like this `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.  But `.*?` just grabs anything up until the closing square brace `\]`, so that'll work just fine as well.

Comment: but again, .*?\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?) there here check only 5 line. what if these values more then 5? cuz its variable. sometime [ITEM X] have 5 value sometimes 8 value. Its variable. How can i do that?

Comment: Hello, so how do you order them if they are variable?  In the above example, we have an array like this `$order_array = array( 1 => 'ID', 2 => 'Color', ...`.  Would all of these be accounted for?  Or are they dynamic too?  If they can all be accounted for, you'd have to approach it a little differently, but still not too difficult.  Basically, just use regex to grab the entire contents of the `[ITEM X]` block and then split that block into lines.  Then do the same thing as before with each line.  Here's a demo so you can see what I'm talking about: http://ideone.com/TWDsVX

Comment: yes this one is completely what im talking about but its return only [ITEM 1]

Comment: Hmmm, it's working in the demo so not sure what the problem would be.  Maybe after [ITEM 2] there aren't at least two newlines or the end of the string?  Just a thought.  Hard to say without actually seeing the file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9p82z4pgFzJU2QwekVqSVBMTmM/view?usp=sharing here is my file, it is a ultima online's script file and i rework like editing these file. there a a lot of files like that and sometimes these values order are different each other. i want to reorder to what i want values until on=@create every [chardef X]

Comment: btw the not working i was talking about, i just c/p ur code and give only [ITEM 1]

Comment: [chardef 666]  
[chardef 222]  
color blue  
color red  
defname c_gargoyle_male  
defname c_zombi  
name gargoyle male  
name zombi now im here. i have to split these :/

Comment: Okay, so I see a couple of problems.  First, the example you gave uses spaces between the words key and value `defname itemname`, but the file you sent uses equal signs `DEFNAME=xxxxxx`.  So you should change the part where it's looking for a space after the key to use an equal sign.  `preg_match('~^\s*'.$val.'\s~i' ...` Change the second `\s` to `=` and it should work.  `preg_match('~^\s*'.$val.'=~i' ...`.  Here is the demo using your file: http://ideone.com/WGevnb

Comment: But that's only one problem.  The second problem is that two of your keys `TSPEECH` are named the same thing, so you're going to have 15 items instead of 16 items in your string.  You'd have to basically check to see if there's already a key with that value in there and if so, increment it.  Otherwise, it's just going to overwrite it with the second value.